# VS 2010 Setup Project requirements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I need to check these things before i procedure with an installation:

1. Does target machine(tm) has installed .NET 3.5?
2. Does tm has installed IIS 6 (win xp) or IIS7 (win 7)?
3. To check which OP is installed the tm... If it is XP, i need to check does it have service pack 3 and is in both cases (xp or win7), is it 32bit or 64bit op?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to know these things? It sounds like bad software design if you are requiring to know this information up front?

Comment: All this is possible with the default setup project.  It being x64 will be tough considering the 64-bit support on Windows XP is horrible.

Answer (score -2):

Use ClickOnce to Deploy your application

> 1. Goto Project Properties
> 2. Click on the Publish Tab
> 3. Add the PreRequisites like .Net 3.5,Sql Server etc
> 4. Publish Now

Else if you are using Setup Deployment Project, you need to write some script to know all these information.

If you are using ClickOnce you can develop small class to know the Service Pack etc

Comment: Very unlikely to be useful if IIS is a prerequisite.